# How stop graphics from being slow despite latest NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, hdmi

Time for yet another graphics card Q. Sorry in advance, but I have tried what I take to be the 'normal' way already (see below), so here it goes:

I have an Intel Atom D525 1.8GHz with a discrete NVIDIA ION 512MB DDR3 graphics card, on which I run (for reasons I will spare you) Ubuntu 11.10. What I want to know is primarily how to fix the laggy behaviour on my current setup. The machine **is** supposed to be able to support HD video. In fact, the spec sheet says:

> - Digital HDMI v1.3 output (DVI via adapter), max. 1920 x 1200
> - Analog VGA output, max. 2048 x 1536
> - NVIDIA PureVideo HD supports full HD decode (1080i/p)

I have the machine connected to the TV via HDMI. Watching small video files (sub 1GB) all is fine, but most often 720p and ALL 1080p video files I have are very sluggish. And watching flash videos via the browser is likewise awful.

I have updated to the latest NVIDIA drivers through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

but with no success: it is just as sluggish as always.

Note (if at all relevant): if instead of playing video directly from my machine, I go via a media server (I use serviio), I can watch the HD content via my TV or PS3.

Finally, here is some additional lspci output:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [ION] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Holco Enterprise Co, Ltd/Shuttle Computer Device 4003
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fe980000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system was so badly beaten up that I decided to upgrade to a still supported version, 12.04, and so after cloning the disk with clonezilla and pressing upgrade (and a lot of waiting), I was happy to see that nothing I cared about was broken, and the video problem was fixed after installing the recommended nvidia drivers. In other words, taking the plunge and upgrading fixed it!